# Rails. Error con delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Estoy automatizando algunos envíos de email en mi aplicación con la gema *delayed_job*. Pues bien, cuando hago `rake jobs:work` y se ejecuta el job, me aparece el siguiente error:

> Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=10) FAILED permanently with
>   Delayed::DeserializationError: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, class:
>   Competition, primary key: 16 (Couldn't find Competition with 'id'=16)

Es decir, va a buscar la competición con `id = 16` que no existe, cuando en realidad la que debería de encontrar es la competición con `id = 23`, que es la que se ha creado en el momento de realizar los *delayed_jobs* que muestro ahora.

¿Alguien me ayuda para ver por qué coge ese `id` y no el que está creando?

Aquí pongo el código:

competitions_controller.rb

```
def create
  @competition = Competition.new(competition_params)

  if @competition.save
    @competition.delay(run_at: @competition.startdate).start_competition
    @competition.delay(run_at: @competition.deadline).finish_competition
    flash[:notice] = "Competition successfully created"
    redirect_to competition_path(@competition)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

competition.rb

```
def finish_competition
  self.update(:finished, true)
  CompetitionMailer.endCompetition(self).deliver_now
end

def start_competition
  self.update(:started, true)
  CompetitionMailer.startCompetition(self).deliver_now
end
```

Para instalar delayed_job he seguido estos pasos:

- Añadir `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'`
  al gemfile
- `bundle install`
- `rails generate delayed_job:active_record`
- `rake db:migrate`
- En `config/application.rb` he añadido `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job`

## Contenido del job

```
#<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job
  id: 21, 
  priority: 0, 
  attempts: 0, 
  handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject:
      !ruby/object:Competition\n  raw_attributes:\n    
      titulo: Competición para prueba de Delayed jobs\n    
      descripcion: hola\n    
      premio: '55555'\n    
      dificultad: Medium\n    
      trainingdata: testPruebaACCURACY.csv\n    
      testdata: testPruebaACCURACY.csv\n    
      metric: Accuracy\n    
      type_competition: classification\n    
      nGroups: '1'\n    
      nWinners: '32'\n    
      deadline: &7 2017-07-18 23:43:00.000000000 Z\n    
      startdate: &9 2017-07-18 23:42:00.000000000 Z\n    
      id: '23'\n     
      created_at: &1 2017-07-18 21:41:04.876321372 Z\n    
      updated_at: *1\n    
      finished: \n    
      started: \n  
      attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet\n    attributes: 
               !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash\n      types:\n        
               id: &3 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :ConnectionAdapters: :PostgreSQL::OID::Integer\n          
                 precision: \n          
                 scale: \n          
                 limit: \n          
                 range: !ruby/range\n            
                 begin: -2147483648\n            
                 end: 2147483648\n            
                 excl: true\n        
               titulo: &2 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::String\n          
                 precision: \n          
                 scale: \n          
                 limit: \n 
               descripcion: &5 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Text\n          
                 precision: \n          
                 scale: \n          
                 limit: \n        
                 premio: *3\n        
                 dificultad: *2\n        
                 created_at: &11 


              !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :AttributeMethods: :TimeZoneConversion: :TimeZoneConverter\n          
               subtype: &4 
               !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :ConnectionAdapters: :PostgreSQL: :OID: :DateTime\n                     precision: \n            
                 scale: \n            
                 limit: \n        
                 updated_at: &12 
               !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :AttributeMethods: :TimeZoneConversion: :TimeZoneConverter\n          
                 subtype: *4\n        
                 deadline: &8 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :AttributeMethods: :TimeZoneConversion: :TimeZoneConverter\n          
                 subtype: *4\n        
                 trainingdata: *2\n        
                 testdata: *2\n        
                 metric: *2\n        
                 type_competition: *2\n        
                 finished: &6 
               !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean\n          
                 precision: \n          
                 scale: \n          
                 limit: \n        
                 started: *6\n        
                 startdate: &10 
               !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :AttributeMethods: :TimeZoneConversion: :TimeZoneConverter\n          
                 subtype: *4\n        
                 nGroups: *3\n        
                 nWinners: *3\n      
                 values:\n        
                 id: \n        
                 titulo: \n        
                 descripcion: \n        
                 premio: \n        
                 dificultad: \n        
                 created_at: \n        
                 updated_at: \n        
                 deadline: \n        
                 trainingdata: \n        
                 testdata: \n        
                 metric: \n        
                 type_competition: \n        
                 finished: \n        
                 started: \n        
                 startdate: \n                             
                 nGroups: \n        
                 nWinners: \n      
                 additional_types: {}\n      
                 materialized: true\n                           
                 delegate_hash:\n        
               titulo: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: titulo\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: Competición para prueba de Delayed jobs\n       
                 type: *2\n          
                 value: Competición para prueba de Delayed jobs\n                                                                                            
               descripcion: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: descripcion\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: Hola\n          
                 type: *5\n          
                 value: dasfas\n        
               premio: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: premio\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: '55555'\n          
                 type: *3\n          
                 value: 55555\n        
               dificultad: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: dificultad\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: Medium\n          
                 type: *2\n          
                 value: Medium\n        
               trainingdata: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: trainingdata\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: testPruebaACCURACY.csv\n                                                    
                 type: *2\n          
                 value: testPruebaACCURACY.csv\n        
               testdata: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n         
                 name: testdata\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: testPruebaACCURACY.csv\n          
                 type: *2\n          
                 value: testPruebaACCURACY.csv\n        
               metric: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: metric\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: Accuracy\n          
                 type: *2\n          
                 value: Accuracy\n        
               type_competition: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: type_competition\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: classification\n          
                 type: *2\n          
                 value: classification\n        
               nGroups: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: nGroups\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: '1'\n          
                 type: *3\n          
                 value: 1\n        
               nWinners: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: nWinners\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: '32'\n          
                 type: *3\n          
                 value: 32\n        
               deadline: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: deadline\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: *7\n          
                 type: *8\n          
                 value: *7\n        
               startdate: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: startdate\n         
                 value_before_type_cast: *9\n          
                 type: *10\n          
                 value: *9\n        
               id: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser\n          
                 name: id\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: '23'\n          
                 type: *3\n          
                 value: 23\n        
               created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: created_at\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: *1\n          
                 type: *11\n          
                 value: *1\n        
               updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromUser\n          
                 name: updated_at\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: *1\n          
                 type: *12\n          
                 value: *1\n        
               finished: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromDatabase\n          
                 name: finished\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: \n          
                 type: *6\n          
                 value: \n        
               started: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord: :Attribute: :FromDatabase\n          
                 name: started\n          
                 value_before_type_cast: \n          
                 type: *6\n          
                 value: \n  
               new_record: false\nmethod_name:                                                                                                                                                    
            :finish_competition\nargs:\n- 23\n" 
  last_error: nil, 
  run_at: "2017-07-18 23:43:00", 
  locked_at: nil, 
  failed_at: nil, 
  locked_by: nil, 
  queue: nil, 
  created_at: "2017-07-18 21:41:05", 
  updated_at: "2017-07-18 21:41:05">
```

Mi versión de Rails es la 4.2.3

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el contenido del `job`? Esto lo puedes ver desde consola de rails con `Delayed::Job.last`.

Comment: Se me pasó... Actualizado!! Como ves, no tiene ni pies ni cabeza, el id en el worker es el 10, y aquí el 21

Comment: Incluye también  la parte que omitiste (`nobject...`), es para confirmar que la serialización se haga sobre el objeto correcto.

Comment: @Gerry, me sale de esa forma. Puede ser ese el fallo. ¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Comment: Cierto, para verlo completo debes utilizar `pp Delayed::Job.last`, o bien, solicita únicamente el `handler`: `Delayed::Job.last.handler`. Cualquiera de las dos opciones te mostrará el texto que falta.

Comment: @Gerry Ya he actualizado, lo he editado lo mejor posible para que lo entiendas. Aún con el handler, sigo sin ver donde puede estar el error

Comment: Es extraño, no veo por ningún lado el `16`; ¿podrías mostrar las relaciones de tu modelo `Competition`?, ¿tienes alguna idea de dónde podría venir el 16? Esto para tratar de reproducir el error localmente (las pruebas que he hecho hasta ahora funcionan).

Comment: `has_many :competition_users
  has_many :users, through: :competition_users`. Esas son las relaciones de mi modelo. Estoy probando a cambiar el código que me mandaste, a ver si puedo ver de donde viene

Comment: @Gerry ya lo he resuelto, pero ahora me encuentro en otro problema que mandaré en otra pregunta. Mi zona horaria es Time +02:00, por lo que los correos me llegan justo dos horas más tarde. Dentro de unas horas lo pondré en otra pregunta. Gracias por intentar ayudarme!  :)

Comment: Excelente! Sería bueno que agregaras la respuesta a tu pregunta (y la aceptes) para que otros usuarios con algún problema similar puedan verla.